# operator() overload and c'tor ambiguity in function objects

Tags: c++, function

assuming we have the next function object:

```
class foo{
private:
    int counter;
public:

    foo(int counter): counter(counter){}
    foo& operator=(const foo& ){...}
    bool operator() (int variable){....}

}

int main(){
    foo f(4);
    foo x(5);
    x = f(4);
    return 0;
 }
```

how does the compiler knows how to respond to:
`x = f(5)`?
I've been searching for a while on the web and in Stack and haven't found exact answer, if its a repost , tell me and i'll delete the question.

Comment: It simply says, `f` is not declared. Anyway I cannot see the ambiguity

Comment: What is `f`? Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a simple method called `eval` to explain it:

```
class foo {
private:
    int counter;

public:

    foo(int counter): counter(counter) {}

    bool operator() (int variable) {
        return variable < counter;
    }

    bool eval(int variable) {
        return variable < counter;
    }
};
```

- `foo` is a class not a method.
- an instance of `foo` can be used like a method.
- calling `foo(5)` will create an instance of `foo` where the `counter = 5`.
- `eval` is a member function of `foo`. *(for now this will do the same as the `()` operator)*

You can call `eval` like this:

```
foo f = foo(5); // create an instance of `foo`
f.eval(3); // returns true    ->   3 < 5
f.eval(0); // returns false   ->   6 < 5
```

You can also use the `()` operator:

```
foo f = foo(5); // create an instance of `foo`
f(3); // returns true    ->   3 < 5
f(0); // returns false   ->   6 < 5
```

**NOTE:**

You can also write (but don't do it):

```
foo f = foo(5); // create an instance of `foo`
f.operator()(3); // returns true    ->   3 < 5
f.operator()(0); // returns false   ->   6 < 5
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends on whether the "(5)" is being used to construct an object or called on an already-existing object:

```
foo f(5); // calls the constructor
f(5);     // calls operator()
```